# Azure Cosmos Java SDK version 4.10.0 throw NoSuchMethodError when trying to connect to Database

Tags: maven, azure-cosmosdb, azure-sdk

I am using Azure cosmos Java SDK version 4.10.0 in spring boot application to connect to Cosmos DB, but it throws "
"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: reactor.util.retry.Retry.withThrowable(Ljava/util/function/Function;)Lreactor/util/retry/Retry;" error.

Code to connect

```
CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClientBuilder()
            .endpoint(<endPoint>)
            .key(<Key>)
            .consistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.SESSION)
            .connectionSharingAcrossClientsEnabled(true)
            .contentResponseOnWriteEnabled(true)
            .userAgentSuffix("my-application1-client")
            .preferredRegions(Collections.singletonList("South Central US"))
            .buildClient();
    cosmosClient.getDatabase(<dbName>).read();
```

While running it throws the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: reactor.util.retry.Retry.withThrowable(Ljava/util/function/Function;)Lreactor/util/retry/Retry;
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.BackoffRetryUtility.executeRetry(BackoffRetryUtility.java:41) ~[azure-cosmos-4.10.0.jar:na]
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxGatewayStoreModel.invokeAsync(RxGatewayStoreModel.java:380) ~[azure-cosmos-4.10.0.jar:na]
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxGatewayStoreModel.processMessage(RxGatewayStoreModel.java:387) ~[azure-cosmos-4.10.0.jar:na]
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.lambda$getDatabaseAccountFromEndpoint$137(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:3549) ~[azure-cosmos-4.10.0.jar:na]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.3.4.RELEASE.jar:3.3.4.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.3.4.RELEASE.jar:3.3.4.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFromMonoOperator.subscribe(FluxFromMonoOperator.java:66) ~[reactor-core-3.3.4.RELEASE.jar:3.3.4.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefer.subscribe(FluxDefer.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.3.4.RELEASE.jar:3.3.4.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.3.4.RELEASE.jar:3.3.4.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.3.4.RELEASE.jar:3.3.4.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable.run(MonoDelay.java:117) ~[reactor-core-3.3.4.RELEASE.jar:3.3.4.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) [reactor-core-3.3.4.RELEASE.jar:3.3.4.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) [reactor-core-3.3.4.RELEASE.jar:3.3.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
```

Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.azure</groupId>
<artifactId>azure-cosmos</artifactId>
<version>4.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Further analysis found that it needs an "io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar" version of 3.3.11.RELEASE but maven is resolving it to use "io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.3.4.RELEASE"

**io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.3.4.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 3.3.11.RELEASE)**

Dependency Tree:

```
[INFO] com.example.sdktest:cosmos:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile - version managed from 1.7.25; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile - version managed from 1.7.25; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile - version managed from 1.7.25; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.25:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.33:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.33:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.18.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile (version managed from 3.3.2.Final)
[INFO] |  |     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile (version managed from 1.3.4)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- com.azure:azure-cosmos:jar:4.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.azure:azure-core:jar:1.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.10.3:compile - version managed from 2.11.3; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.10.3:compile (version managed from 2.11.3)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile (version managed from 2.3.2)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile - version managed from 1.2.1; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:6.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- (org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile - version managed from 1.7.25; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.3.4.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 3.3.11.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:2.0.30.Final:compile (version managed from 2.0.34.Final)
[INFO] |  +- com.azure:azure-core-http-netty:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.53.Final)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - version managed from 4.1.53.Final; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- (io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |     +- (io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |     \- (io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.53.Final)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - version managed from 4.1.53.Final; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - version managed from 4.1.53.Final; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - version managed from 4.1.53.Final; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.53.Final)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - version managed from 4.1.53.Final; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - version managed from 4.1.53.Final; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - version managed from 4.1.53.Final; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.53.Final)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - version managed from 4.1.53.Final; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.48.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.53.Final)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - version managed from 4.1.53.Final; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - version managed from 4.1.53.Final; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-kqueue:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.48.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.53.Final)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - version managed from 4.1.53.Final; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - version managed from 4.1.53.Final; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:jar:0.9.6.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 0.9.13.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |     +- (io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - version managed from 4.1.53.Final; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     +- (io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - version managed from 4.1.53.Final; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     +- (io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - version managed from 4.1.53.Final; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     +- (io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile - version managed from 4.1.53.Final; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     +- (io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.48.Final:compile - version managed from 4.1.53.Final; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     \- (io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.3.4.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.3.11.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner:jar:2.10.3:compile (version managed from 2.11.2)
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:4.1.5:compile (version managed from 4.1.0)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile - version managed from 1.7.25; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.3.6:compile (version managed from 1.5.6)
[INFO] |     +- (org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.11:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.1.12)
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    |  \- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  \- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO]    |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:test - version managed from 1.7.25; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- (jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile - version managed from 2.3.2; scope updated from test; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.5.2:test
[INFO]    |  |     \- (org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  \- (org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.5.2:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO]    |     +- (org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |     +- (org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.5.2:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |     \- (org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.5.2:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.5.2:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  \- (org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.5.2:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- (org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.1.0:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  \- (org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.5.2:test - version managed from 5.4.2; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.13.2:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.8:test (version managed from 1.9.10)
[INFO]    |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.8:test (version managed from 1.9.10)
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO]    +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO]    +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile - scope updated from test; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.4:test
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the .read() function you are calling.

If you want a reference to a database object look at this sample below.

```
database = client.getDatabase(databaseName);
```

For more Java SDK samples look here [Azure Cosmos DB Java SQL API Samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-java-sql-api-samples)

Comment: Thanks for the response .. the issue seems to be not with read() function. I debugged it a little more and to me issue seems to be with dependency. I was running with spring boot version 2.2.6.RELEASE and it was fetching reactor-core:3.3.4.RELEASE version. I switched my spring boot version to 2.3.6.RELEASE and it fetched reactor-core:3.3.11.RELEASE version and the above program did not throw any error after that.